# Bootstrap - Parsley color display radio button error message after submit

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, parsley.js

I'm trying to understand how to highlight radio buttons using parsley validation.

http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html

is a parsley sample that does what i'd like to do, except it uses data-parsley-validate on the form tag which you are "not supposed to do"

I've tried to duplicate the simple page on fiddle..

```
<label for="gender">Gender *:</label>
<p>
M: <input name="gender" id="genderM" value="M" required="" type="radio">
F: <input name="gender" id="genderF" value="F" type="radio">
</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bwolfsohn/9wfjo94w/7/

but i can't get the radio button line to display in pink on fiddle like it does on the simple sample.

1. What am i doing wrong in the fiddle ?
2. is there a way to accomplish this without using  data-parsley-validate="" on the form itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the CSS, Add these to your CSS:

```
p.parsley-error {
    color: #B94A48;
    background-color: #F2DEDE;
    border: 1px solid #EED3D7;
}


p.parsley-success {
    color: #468847;
    background-color: #DFF0D8;
    border: 1px solid #D6E9C6;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLyt5oxr/)

Comment: that was it.. i must have missed that somewhere... and, it works without the data-parsley-validate="" on the form...